# Why the app/code folder is empty?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.7

While installing Magento 2 (the recent stable version is Magento 2.0.7), I used different ways except archive/download.

The first used is Git clone:

```
$ git clone -b 2.0 git@github.com:magento/magento2.git
```

Then, another one is Composer

```
$ composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition magento2
```

Then, the rest of the installation procedures are the same. And both ways could setup Magento 2 properly.

Whey use "git clone..." created the **app/code/Magento**, but compare with "composer create-project..." the **app/code** is empty?

Is "app/code/Magento" does not exist won't affect any other procedures? 
Such as installing 3rd party module or self created module in "app/code/Custom_module"?

Answer (score 4):

When you create the project with composer all modules placed in vendor directory.

Pay attention then you should use git clone only in case you have to contribute to Magento project.

Empty app/code should not affect any processes.

Comment: Understand, so, composer create-project is like using the distribution version, vs the git clone is getting source code from Magento 2. Therefore, the git clone put all Magento 2 modules under "app/code" folder for contributors.  The "app/code" folder is the place to put my own modules.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 is using composer and all modules are separate entity this time.
They are separately developed and get updates, modules for 2.0 which are available will also be downloaded in vendor folder which is the standard way of code sharing. You can find then in [packagist](https://packagist.org/).
Composer is a dependency manager for php development.
You will only have your code in `app/code` directory. All community code will be in vendor directory.
For better understanding with this and why we in Magento using this, You should read [PHP Standards Recommendations](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Comment: Thank you for your reference links to packagist and psr. They are helpful for me, as a front-end developer to understand further PHP standard.

Comment: you can accept the answer if you found this helpful for you.